# jQuery: Adding td element to a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using a `row` variable to get data dynamically and set the table row.

```
var row = '<tr>'+
      '<td>'+obj.Message+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+obj.Error+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+obj.Detail+'</td>'+
      '</tr>';
```

Based a value I tried to add another `<td>` to the row object but it didn't work.

```
if(obj.Type=='Error') {
  $(row).find('td:last').append('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>');
}
$('table> tbody:last').append(row);
```

First I tried to just append the `<td>` to row but that didn't work as well.

```
$(row).append('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>');
```

Comment: It is `==` `if(obj.Type=='Error') { ...` not `=`

Comment: It's worth mentioning to him that that wouldn't stop his code trying to add the cell.  It would make it try to add the cell every time, regardless of `obj.Type`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're not storing the last row.

When you call `$(row).find(...).append(...)` the result is not being stored in a variable. The best solution is probably keeping a jQuery object from the start:

```
//         v--- use a jQuery object here
var $row = $('<tr>'+
      '<td>'+obj.Message+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+obj.Error+'</td>'+
      '<td>'+obj.Detail+'</td>'+
      '</tr>');    
if(obj.Type=='Error') {
    $row.append('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>');
}
$('table> tbody:last').append($row);
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7BU6m/)

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I made a typo which has been corrected (line 1).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `append` use [after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) and use `===` (or `==`) instead of `=`

```
  if(obj.Type === 'Error') {
    $(row).find('td:last').after('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>'); //This will add the new td after the last one
   ..
```

or just append it to the row:

```
   $(row).append('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode +'</td>'); //this will do the same thing, less code and append this as last td of your row.
```

Answer (score 0):

use `==` comparision operator for comparision:
To insert new cell use .after() or you can just append whole row using `.append()`

```
if(obj.Type=='Error') {
   $(row).append('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your appending INSIDE a `td`, you want `.after`

```
if(obj.Type=='Error') {
    $(row).find('td:last').after('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>');
}
```

And the whole, `==` over `=` is an issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have done mistake here:

```
 obj.Type='Error'
```

(=)act as assignment operator here.

Check with

```
  if(obj.Type=='Error'){
   //hence code.
  }
```

Comment: That was a typo. I have fixed it.

Comment: So you can accept answer from above which you feel appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to add `row` to the DOM before you can search it and add another `<td>`?

**Solution 1**

```
var row = '<tr>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Message+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Error+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Detail+'</td>';

if(obj.Type=='Error') {
    row += '<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>';
}

row += '</tr>';

$('table> tbody:last').append(row);
```

**Solution 2**

```
var row = '<tr>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Message+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Error+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Detail+'</td>'+
          '</tr>';

$('table').append(row);

if(obj.Type=='Error') {
    $('table').find('td:last').after('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>');
}
```

**Solution 3**

```
var row = '<tr>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Message+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Error+'</td>'+
          '<td>'+obj.Detail+'</td>'+
          '</tr>';

$('table').append(row);

if(obj.Type=='Error') {
    $('table tr').append('<td>'+ obj.ErrorCode+'</td>');
}
```